# Python module and __all__

Tags: python, module

I trying to understand how to manage module with `__all`. For example, I have following structured code:

```
main.py
|=> /database
    |=> __init__.py
    |=> engine (with variables engine, session, etc.)
```

now I want to be able to import `session` and `engine` instances directly from `database` module like:

```
from database import session
```

I tried to add line `__all__ = ['session']` or `__all__ = ['engine.session']` to `__init__py` but when I trying to do import I've got an exception `AttributeError: 'modile' object has not attribute 'engine.session'`.

Is there any way to achieve wanted behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Listing names in `__all__` does not, by itself, import items into a module. All it does is list names to import from that module if you used `from database import *` syntax.

Import `session` into `database/__init__.py`:

```
from .engine import session
```

Comment: Thank you for solution, but I still have a question - if I importting all required classes/functions/variables in `__init__.py` I can do not bother about filling `__all__` - all I imported already available. So, what which reasons to use `__all__`?

Comment: @AlexG.P.: use `__all__` to flag what names are 'importable'; if someone does `from database import *` only names listed in `__all__` will be imported, rather than **all** names in the namespace of the module.

Comment: Ahh, it only can descrease ramges of imported types, but not increase it. Great thanks.