# cannot load sub-packages in a python package using `__all__` in the `__init__.py` file

Tags: python, module, package, init

I want to load sub-packages using the `__all__` attribute in the uppermost `__init__.py` file rather than using `import`s there, but unfortunately, I cannot get it to work.

Here a simplified example:

I have my package

```
pdbsr/
     __init__.py*
     ...
     extras/
         __init__.py
         ...
```

`*` this asterisk should highlight the `__init__` file that I am talking about below.

So when I put the line

```
import extras
```

into the `__init__.py` file, everything works fine. When I test the module in the interpreter I get the following response, which shows me that the module was successfully loaded:

```
>>> import pdbsr
>>> pdbsr.extras
<module 'pdbsr.extras' from '.../site-packages/pdbsr/extras/__init__.pyc'>
```

In a new python shell, after I replaced the `import extras` in the `__init__.py` file by

```
__all__ = ["extras"]
```

I get a problem:

```
>>> import pdbsr
>>> pdbsr.extras
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'extras'
>>> extras
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'extras' is not defined
```

Anyone has an idea what I have to do to load the sub-packages via `__all__`?

### EDIT:

I apologize for the very bad example given above. 
So my initial thought was that I could simplify my `__init__.py` file.
For example, right now I

```
`from pdbfile.new_pdb import *`
`from pdbfile.[...] import *`
`from pdbfile.[...] import *`
```

and so forth. Since I have a lot of `.py` files for each sub-package, my `__init__` file becomes really huge.

For example, pdbsr/pdb_file/new_pdb contains class `NewPdb()`, which I could call in the interpreter

```
>>> import pdbsr
>>> new = pdbsr.NewPdb()
```

(I want to avoid further dot notations, like `pdbsr.new_pdb.NewPdb()`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python module and \_\_all\_\_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236895/python-module-and-all)

Answer (score 0):

That is not what `__all__` does. `__all__` is a list of the members of the module that will be visible when the module is imported. Using `import` in the `__init__` files as you were doing before is probably the best way to load packages, unless you have some special reason why that wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. But I am still a little bit unsure of what you mean by "visible". I also added an EDIT section to my question, since I realized that I have chosen a very bad example before