# What else is required to run function in modules added into __all__

Tags: python

This seemed like a straight forward alteration. Move functioning code into a subdirectory.

I successfully recreated the code described below, but when I altered the example by putting the `./plugins` directory one level down the tree, I got the following error:

```
module 'main' has no attribute 'handle_pony'
```

To update my code after the directory change,

1) Importing from `./main.py` I added the dot syntax: `from app_config.plugins import *`

2) Added empty `__init__.py` files in the new sub-directory.

**What else is required to update the module so `run()` is callable as described?** What Python concept am I missing?

---

I'm working on creating a module with a **dynamic-loading plugin system** as described here: [Dispatcher Pattern Safety](http://drunkenpython.org/dispatcher-pattern-safety.html)

Here is my basic tree where I moved the plugins into a sub-folder `app_config`,

```
./main.py
./__init__.py (empty)
./app_config/__init__.py (empty)
./app_config/plugins
./app_config/plugins/__init__.py (sets __all__)
./app_config/plugins/handle_pony.py
```

The original example (link) loads the module into `__all__` in  `plugins/__init__.py`:

```
# FILE ./plugins/__init__.py
# Moved to ./app_config/plugins/__init__.py
import os, glob 
# REMOVED __all__ FROM ORIGINAL POST
modules = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'handle_*.py'))
__all__ = [ os.path.basename(f)[:-3] 
    for f in modules if os.path.isfile(f) 
    and not f.endswith('__init__.py')]
```

The plugin was working as described in the linked blog post, and the correct plugin is named in the error as `handler_pony`. Calling `run()` nevertheless fails:

```
# ./main.py
import sys 
## Original
# from plugins import * 
from app_config.plugins import *
datatype = 'pony'  # Datatype value for illustration
getattr(sys.modules[__name__], 'handle_' + datatype).run()
```

Similar post [Python module and `__all__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17236963)

Comment: What does `for path in __path__` do?

Comment: this part is not valid python code, please update `__all__ = [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(handler))[0] 
    for path in __path__ 
    for handler in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, 'handle_*.py'))]`

Comment: That code is in the original linked blog post. That said, on second look that's not what I used. Updating.